# How can I exclude a subclass (or subclasses) of pages from Wagtail's search functionality?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm creating a blog site for a friend and there are certain page models that I would like to be excluded from users' searches. These models are `BlogIndexPage` and `ThankYouPage`. Both of these models subclass `wagtail.models.Page`. I want to have control over how these pages are visited and therefore don't want links for them to show up in search results if users search—for example—*thank* or *blog*.

For context, this is the `search` view function:

```py
def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get("query", None)
    page = request.GET.get("page", 1)

    # Search
    if search_query:
        search_results = (
            Page.objects.live().order_by("-first_published_at").search(search_query)
        )
        query = Query.get(search_query)

        # Record hit
        query.add_hit()
    else:
        search_results = Page.objects.none()

    # etc...
```

I've tried the two solutions suggested in this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427735/wagtail-indexing-exclude-some-content-or-use-queryset) and a third solution I found in the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/search/indexing.html#disabling-model-indexing), but they did not solve my problem. Specifically I tried the following:

```py
class ThankYouPage(Page):
    ...

    # Method One:
    @classmethod
    def get_indexed_objects(cls):
        return cls.objects.none()

    # Method Two:
    def get_indexed_instance(self):
        return None

    # Method Three:
    search_fields = []
```

I ran the `update_index` management command after each change.

In the Django shell, I get the following behavior:

```py
>>> from wagtail.models import Page
>>> from apps.contact.models import ThankYouPage
>>>
>>> Page.objects.all().search("thank")
<SearchResults [<Page: Thank You Page>]>
>>>
>>> ThankYouPage.objects.all().search("thank")
<SearchResults []>
>>>
```

The issue seems to be that the `.search()` method returns a list-like object of `Page` instances instead of specific subclass instances. I can solve this issue by adding an `.exclude()` method to the search queryset:

```py
excluded_page_ids = [
    4,   # BlogIndexPage
    26,  # ThankYouPage
]

def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get("query", None)
    page = request.GET.get("page", 1)

    # Search
    if search_query:
        search_results = (
            Page.objects.live()
            .exclude(id__in=excluded_page_ids)  # Manually exclude certain pages
            .order_by("-first_published_at")
            .search(search_query)
        )
        query = Query.get(search_query)

        # Record hit
        query.add_hit()
    else:
        search_results = Page.objects.none()

    # etc...
```

But this *feels* like an unsustainable bad practice. Is there a more pythonic or wagtailian way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Set `search_fields =[]` in the page subclasses you do not want in search results. https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/topics/search/indexing.html#disabling-model-indexing

Comment: I included that exact same link in my post along with an explanation that I already tried doing that. Is there something I need to do in addition to that? It doesn't seem to work by itself.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. What version of Wagtail are you using and which search backend?

Comment: No worries! I'm sure I wrote more than I needed to for this question. Wagtail version is 5.0.1 and the search backend is just the database's full text search (sqlite for dev, MySQL for production).